# Flow-router +react ssr, how to handle POST form submit when js is off?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

one customer condition is that the page can function wen even javascript is disabled, I managed to do SSR but can't handle the basic form submit, how to get the parameters from POST after a submit, and whats the best way to implement this?

Comment: How have you implemented SSR? I think you should use the same system to implement the server-side handler for your form.

Comment: with flow-router but their docs they only have info on how to use GET